# Filter SQL SELECT by XML node

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

There are single `SQL` Table with `xml`-type field:

---

```
| EntityId | EntityType  | Xml column                |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1        | Employee    | `<productId>1</productId>`|
------------------------------------------------------
| 1        | Product     | `<name>apple</name>`      |
------------------------------------------------------
| 7        | Shop        | `<country>...</country>`  |                      |   
-----------------------------------------------------|
```

What I need is a to filter table row by `Xml` node value:

```
SELECT * WHERE (EntityId='1' AND EntityType='Employee') 
OR ( EntityId=SomeFuncToGetXmlFieldByNodeName('productId') )
```

Can u point me on how to write that `SomeFuncToGetXmlFieldByNodeName(fieldName)`

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, table html is a bit corrupted. As you can see, its like 3 tables stored in 1, with xml field that store relation between them. I need to get that realation for every row matched condition, and select extra rows based on that

Comment: It is difficult to understand your problem. Have you looked at MS SQL Server documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want a function like this.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SomeFuncToGetXmlFieldByNodeName]
(
    @NodeName nvarchar(100),
    @XML xml
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @XML.value('(*[local-name(.) = sql:variable("@NodeName")]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
END
```

It takes a node name and a some XML as parameter and returns the value in the node.

Use the function like this:

```sql
select T.EntityId,
       T.EntityType,
       T.[Xml column]
from YourTable as T
where T.EntityID = 1 and
      T.EntityType = 'Employee' or
      T.EntityId = dbo.SomeFuncToGetXmlFieldByNodeName('productId', T.[Xml column])
```

Instead of using the above I want to recommend you to try a query that does not use the scalar valued function. It uses [exist() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) instead.

```sql
select T.EntityId,
       T.EntityType,
       T.[Xml column]
from YourTable as T
where T.EntityID = 1 and
      T.EntityType = 'Employee' or
      T.[Xml column].exist('/productId[. = sql:column("T.EntityID")]') = 1
```

Comment: Looks like exactly what I want. Thank you. I will test it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx)!

The "query" method is likely what you'll need. See examples in the linked article.

Comment: Thank you for help, info about exist(..) and value(..) methods are helpful. I promise, to vote up your answer later, when I have enough reputation)